# Sum from sub query inside WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I would like to know how I can access the result of sub query and use it as condition in the main query

**Here is my query code:**

```
SELECT m.*, dp.department as dep, 
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) FROM time_management tm WHERE tm.user = m.id AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(`date`)= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) ) as time
FROM members m 
LEFT JOIN department dp ON m.department = dp.id 
WHERE m.department = $departmentvar AND tm.time > 34
```

As you can see I am trying to have last condition in the WHERE clause time to select only the results which SUM is bigger than 34.

is that possible with sub query ?

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: why not just have a "having clause" on the subquery...   `...AND YEAR(date)= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) HAVING SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) > 34`

Comment: @xQbert . . . Because that expression is in a subquery.

Comment: hmm... I'll have to try it maybe mySQLs implementation is a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause so you can write the query as:

```
SELECT m.*, dp.department as dep, 
       (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) )
        FROM time_management tm
        WHERE tm.user = m.id AND
              MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
              YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
       ) as time
FROM members m LEFT JOIN
     department dp
     ON m.department = dp.id 
WHERE m.department = $departmentvar 
HAVING time > 34;
```

The `time` in the `HAVING` clause should be interpreted as the alias defined in the `SELECT`.

In most other databases, you would use a subquery.  However, MySQL materializes subqueries, which incurs extra overhead.

Also, I don't think the `LEFT JOIN` is needed here -- unless you have departments that are not in the `departments` table.

Comment: last sentence is a bit off.  maybe `--- unless you have members that do not have a department.`

Comment: @xQbert . . . It is stranger than that because of the `where` clause.  There would have to be a valid (i.e. non-`NULL`) department id in `members` with no corresponding value in `department`.